# How does Spring work after websocket connection established?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have Java project using Spring. I have several controllers. I have also created WebSocket:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websockettest")
public class WebSocketTest 
{
    private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(Session peer, String message) {
        return message;
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen (Session peer) throws IOException{
        peers.add(peer);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose (Session peer) {
        peers.remove(peer);
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me, after websocket connection established, are all my requests to my controllers going to be transferred through this websocket?
Thank you!

Comment: Try it on your own instead of asking questions that are too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a Controller Class

```
@Controller
class AccountsController {
@GetMapping("/homepage"){
//code here....
}}
```

It will not accessible by the socket and you can create separate end points for the sockets as follows below

```
@MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
```

However you can use the same controller for the Websocket mapping and URL mapping

You can also check the website for more information about the spring WebSocket, the answer is quite broad to explain so I'm just summing up,

Please have a look into this as well
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/